# Why is yyerror() being called even when string is valid?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

This is a yacc program to recognize all strings ending with b preceded by n a’s using the grammar a n b (note: input n value).

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
a {return A;}
b {return B;}
\n {return 0;}
. {return yytext[0];}
%%
```

The yacc part

```
YACC PART
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int aCount=0,n;
%}
%token A
%token B
%%
s : X  B {   if (aCount<n || aCount>n) 
        {
    YYFAIL();
}
 }
X : X T | T
T : A { aCount++;} 
  ;
%%

int main()
{   printf("Enter the value of n \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    yyparse();
    printf("Valid string\n");
}

int YYFAIL()
{
    printf("Invalid count of 'a'\n");
    exit(0);
}

int yyerror()
{
    printf("Invalid string\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

output

```
invalid string
```

It displays invalid string even for valid string like aab for n value 2.
For every string i enter,yyerror() is called.
Please help me resolve this!
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

reads a number from standard input.

It does not read a number and the following newline. It just reads a number. Whatever follows the number will be returned from the next operation which reads from `stdin`.

So when you attempt to parse, the character read by the lexer is the newline character which you typed after the number. That newline character causes the lexer to return 0 to the parser, which the parser interprets as the end of input. But the grammar doesn't allow empty inputs, so the parser reports a syntax error.

On my system, the parser reports a syntax error before it gives me the opportunity to type any input. The fact that it allows you to type an input line is a bit puzzling to me, but it might have something to do with whatever IDE you are using to run your program.

Comment: I wasn't able to enter the input either but after entering a number and giving space, I was able to enter the input.What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @tanisha: the usual advice applies. [Don't use scanf.](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). Instead, use `fgets()` to read the entire line and then use `strtol` to extract the integer from the character string. (Or `sscanf`, but `strtol` is simpler and better.)